# Distribution of $min(x,\frac{1}{2})$

Tags: probability, statistics, uniform-distribution

We have a random variable $X$ which is uniformly $U(0,1)$ distributed. It is required to obtain the PDF of $min(x,\frac{1}{2})$.

**My approach**

If $x<\frac{1}{2}$, Y = x
If $x\geq\frac{1}{2}$, Y = \frac{1}{2}

I am not able to translate the above information into the PDF. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This random variable does not have a PDF, since it has a positive probability of equaling $1/2$.

Comment: its support is $[0,1/2]$, has density $1/2$ along the interval $[0,1/2)$ and mass $1/2$ at the point $(1/2)$

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y=X\wedge\frac12$, then $$Y = X\cdot\mathsf 1_{\left(0,\frac12\right)}(X) + \frac12\cdot \mathsf 1_{\left[\frac12,1\right)}(X).$$
It follows that
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Y\leqslant y) &= \mathbb P\left(Y\leqslant y, 0<X<\frac12 \right) + \mathbb P\left(Y\leqslant y, \frac12\leqslant X<1 \right)\\
&= y\cdot \mathsf 1_{\left(0,\frac12\right)}(y) + \mathsf 1_{\left[\frac12,\infty\right)}(y).
\end{align}